# should this definition of $a$ divides $b$ be changed?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I just started a class in Number theory today and we were given a definition of what it means to say a divides b.

The definition goes as follows.

We say $b$ is a divisor of $a$ or $a$ is a multiple of $b$ if $a$ divides $b$. We write $a|b$.

But if $a$ divides $b$, doesn't this imply that $a$ is a divisor of $b$?

Also on Wikipedia it gives the opposite of what's stated in this definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor.

So shouldn't the definition I stated actually read at the end

if $b$ divides $a$ we write $b|a$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right, it should be:

We say $a$ is a divisor of $b$ or $b$ is a multiple of $a$ if $a$ divides $b.$ We write $a|b.$

Comment: I knew it, must have just been a small typographical error on my lecturers part

Comment: It is easy to switch it around accidentally in the heat of the moment